# OJS Error in search page, after upgrading to OJS version from version 3.3.0.13 to version 3.3.0.14

Tags: php, ojs

After upgrading OJS version from 3.3.0.13 to 3.3.0.14 I start having problems in search page.

The advanced search parameters not showing, and I get the following error in PHP:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in
> ….\lib\pkp\lib\vendor\php81_bc\strftime\src\php-8.1-strftime.php:60\nStack

[image: OJS search page without advanced search parameters]

I try to clean cache, but the problem maintains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because I dot not have the php extension php_intl setting in my system.
The solution was adding the “extension=php_intl.dll” line in my php.ini configuration file.